# Should I be able to review Close Votes on a question that I have answered?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, vote-to-close

Whilst doing some reviewing of the Close Vote queue, I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5212527) that I just answered.

I thought it was a simple question but not worthy of closing, hence I answered it.

I know I could still vote to close it via the question directly, but should it show me a question from the queue that I've clearly already seen and answered?

I suppose I could be bias, and say it should stay open, so it should be up to other people that haven't answered it to vote on if it should be closed.

By answering it I'm indirectly saying it shouldn't be closed.

Ps I've tagged this as a bug, but it might just be by design?

Comment: Voting to close a question and answering it are totally independent activities.

Comment: @gunr2171 I understand that, my point is I've viewed it and would have voted to close it if I felt it deserved closing rather than answering it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with answering and close voting. At most it's "unofficially impolite" because you deny other people an opportunity at an answer while highlighting your own. Also, the VTC queue does not show you answers on purpose. If the _question_ should be closed, regardless of the answers (even your own), it should be closed.

Comment: @gunr2171 except, of course, doing both might gain you some weird looks in the process

Comment: That's where my point on bias comes in, surely it's for other people to judge outside of the asker and answerers of the question.

Comment: @gunr2171 The whole point of voting to close is to say that the question should not be answered.  That is *completely* at odds with actually answering it.  Either you feel that the post should be answered, or you think it shouldn't.  If it shouldn't be answered, you should vote to close and not answer.  If it should be answered, then answer it and don't vote to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Servy and others have explained this rather well. Voting to close questions is *independent* of answering them. To quote gunr2171, "If the question should be closed, regardless of the answers (even your own), it should be closed."

This was [discussed in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175864/etiquette-for-casting-close-vote-in-the-close-votes-review-queue-for-a-question) - quoting [Mad Scientist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175864/etiquette-for-casting-close-vote-in-the-close-votes-review-queue-for-a-question/175868#175868):

> I don't see this as a conflict of interest, if you answered the question you should be convinced that it is a reasonable question that should stay open, and voting in review that way would be the correct course of action.